# FFmpeg - confused with the concept of audio frame size and its calculation

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, codec, pcm

I'm learning video and audio codecs with FFmpeg. I'm strgulling to understand  frame size and some other concepts.

**Frame size
This is the size in bytes of each frame. This can vary a lot: if each sample
is 8 bits, and we’re handling mono sound, the frame size is one byte.
Similarly in 6 channel audio with 64 bit floating point samples, the frame size is 48 bytes** ([PCM Terminology and Concepts](https://larsimmisch.github.io/pyalsaaudio/terminology.html))

As described above, if each sample is 8 bits and there are 6 channels, then the frame size will be 48 bytes. The result from my code was 96 (16 bits * 6 channels). On the other side, the result from the call `stream->codecpar->frame_size` was 1024. Why were they different? Is the frame size 1024 for 6 channels or just each channel?

**main.cpp:**

```
else if (stream->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
    std::cout << "audio sample rate: " << stream->codecpar->sample_rate << std::endl;
    std::cout << "audio bits: " << stream->codecpar->bits_per_coded_sample << std::endl;
    std::cout << "audio channels: " << stream->codecpar->channels << std::endl;
    std::cout << "audio frame size: " << stream->codecpar->frame_size << std::endl; 
    std::cout << "audio frame size: (16bits * 6 channels) = " << stream->codecpar->channels * stream->codecpar->bits_per_coded_sample << std::endl; 
    audio_stream_index = i;
}
```

**console:**

```
audio sample rate: 48000
audio bits: 16
audio channels: 6
audio frame size: 1024
audio frame size: (16bits * 6 channels) = 96
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In FFmpeg, audio frame size refers to samples, not bytes. So one audio frame of a 16-bit 4-channel PCM stream will have  1024 x 16 x 4 = 65536 bits  = 8192 bytes.

Comment: makes sense now. but what does the actual frame size means. Take the above 16bits * 6 channel = 96 bits as an example. I want to know the difference between them

Comment: The page you linked to relates to ALSA - I wouldn't treat them as universal definitions.